# What's the best way to provide a spreadsheet as an answer to a question?

Tags: support

What's the best way to include a spreadsheet in an answer? Is there a good archival site where I can upload a spreadsheet so that it exists independent of my personal accounts?

For example, I recently answered this question, [County list of Woodard's American Nations](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17634/county-list-of-woodards-american-nations). Since the answer is a dataset that I made myself, it's not available from another source. I added it to my Google Sheets and shared a public link, but it seems like there must be a better way. I don't want to keep this sheet around forever cluttering up my google account.

Comment: CSV gist on GitHub? Pastebin and archive.org?

Comment: @philshem came to say this. make it an answer if ya like!

Comment: i would also add, depending on its length, simply embedding the table in markdown here.